# Como resolver o erro "git clone problem with the ssl CA cert"?

Tags: git, ssl

Estou tentando instalar o SSL Let's Encrypt, utilizando o certbot, estou usando o seguinte comando:

```
git clone https://github.com/certbot/certbot
```

Porém a seguinte mensagem retorna:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/certbot/certbot/': Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Gostaria de saber o que devo fazer para corrigir este problema.

Comment: Você realmente precisa (precisa mesmo) clonar? É tão fácil instalar o certbot usando o repositório da distribuição...

Answer (score 3):

## Aplicando um bypass

Pode tentar um bypass, ou seja, desativar a verificação do ssl nas configurações ou em tempo de execução.

**Modifica globalmente, via linha de comando**

```
git config http.sslVerify false
```

**Modifica em tempo de execução, ou seja, somente para a sessão corrente**

```
env GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://git.....
```

Esteja ciente de que há implicações com segurança ao desativar a verificação. Use esse recurso somente quando for inevitável.

**Outro jeito grosseiro é no arquivo de configurações do git, remover a linha**

```
[http]
sslCAinfo = /local/do/cert/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

## Configurando um certificado válido (cacert.pem)

Todavia, o correto é configurar um certificado válido.

Para isso, faça o download do cacert.pem:

```
curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /local/onde/quer/salvar/cacert.pem
```

Então edite o arquivo de configurações do git

```
[http]
sslCAinfo = /local/onde/salvou/o/cacert.pem
```

**Dica:** Outro modo de editar as configurações por linha de comando:

```
git config --global http.sslCAinfo "/local/onde/salvou/o/cacert.pem"
```

Comment: Daniel, muito obrigado. Infelizmente estou com um erro de permissão. Creio que vou ter que resetar o servidor.

Pois consegui passar as primeiras partes da instalação automática, porém, não estou conseguindo finalizar a instalação porque  "default-ssl.conf.save" não esta acessível.